# How to represent MySQL Bit Type in Swift 3

Tags: php, json, swift

My current database consist of Bit type object, to represent a boolean variable. [image]

However, when I tried to grab this data from MySQL to Swift 3, it returns Nil. I know that my PHP file works fine because when I run my PHP code alone, it prints out the correct set of values.

PHP File

```
<?php
session_start();
$current_username = $_SESSION["username"];
$current_password = $_SESSION["password"];

// open database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","fridge_items");
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root", "root", "fridge_items");

// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
} 
//Getting the user_id 
$query_id = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE username='$current_username'";
$result_id = $mysqli->query($query_id);

/* associative array */
//Fetches the user id 
$row_id = $result_id->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$user_id = $row_id["id"];

//Fetches the user id 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items where user_id='$user_id'";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

//Close connections 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I commented out the status variable, it prints out the correct values. So I am thinking that it is returning nil because Bool is not the correct way to represent the Bit type in MySQL. I tried Int, NSInteger, but none of them works. So I am really not sure what type actually represents status (Bit Type). 
Swift File

```
/*
* Fetching items from database
*/
func fetchItems() -> Void {

    let url: String = "http://localhost/fridge_app/fetchItems.php" //this will be changed to the path where service.php lives

     //created NSURL
     let requestURL = NSURL(string: url)

     //creating NSMutableURLRequest
     let request = URLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)

     //creating a task to send the post request
     let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
         data, response, error in

          //exiting if there is some error
          if error != nil {
              print("error is \(error)")
              return;
          }

          // Grabbing the items 
          var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
          do {
              jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

          } catch let error as NSError {
              print(error)
          }

          var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
          let items: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

          for i in 0 ... jsonResult.count-1
          {
              jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary
              let item = itemModel()
              print(jsonElement["status"])

              //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
              if let name = jsonElement["name"] as? String,
                  let status = jsonElement["status"] as? Bool
                  /*let date_in = jsonElement["date_in"] as? NSDate,
                  let count = jsonElement["count"] as? NSInteger,
                  let image = jsonElement["image"] as? NSObjectFileImage,
                  let expiration_date = jsonElement["expiration_date"] as? NSDate,
                  let item_id = jsonElement["item_id"] as? NSInteger*/
                {
                    item.name = name
                    item.status = status
                    /*item.date_in = date_in
                    item.count = count
                    item.image = image
                    item.expiration_date = expiration_date
                    item.item_id = item_id*/
                }
                items.add(item)
                print(item)
            }
        }
        //executing the task
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: The PHP code is reading from DB, the Swift one is parsing a JSON, they are not equivalent. Your problem likely comes from the json interpretation, not from the `Bit` value from the database.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, so how should i represent jsonElement["status"] then

Comment: Then please update the question then, in it's current form is misleading

Comment: Regarding `jsonElement["status"]`, do a `print(type(of: jsonElement["status"]))` to see what type does it have.

Comment: It prints as type any

Comment: JSON has only 6 data types -- object, array, string, number, boolean and null. Usually you need to choose the most appropriate type for each field on the server side. You are just passing the results of `fetch_object()` to `json_encode()`, in most cases which does not generate a desired JSON output. Anyway, if you want to fix this situation only on the client side, you need to know what sort of output your php code generates. See what you get with `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)`.

Answer (score -2):

I have found solution. Instead of casting status to a specific type, I made it a type Any. Like shown below. Now it works

```
var status: Any!
```